# Have certain apps/ports bypass OpenVPN connection

Tags: networking, server, openvpn, plex

I have an ubuntu server (22.04.3) that is running a Plex server and various downloading software. I'd like to have a VPN running to protect me, however when I do this, remote access becomes unavailable in Plex.

Is there a way I can configure certain apps/certain ports to bypass OpenVPN completely, or is there a different way to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can't access Plex by going to https://app.plex.tv ?  I thought that Plex if successful will communicate with the Central Plex Server giving you access no matter where you are.  But, that is good to know if you can't communicate with it through the VPN as that will keep me off of it then because I am not aware of telling an app as to what connection / IP address to use.

Comment: @Terrance I can use app.plex.tv to access it as well as all the apps, but only on my network. If I try to access it from anywhere else, then it doesn't work. That's what I'm trying to figure out how to solve.

Comment: Interesting.  I am not running a VPN on mine to test this out, but it looks like on my favorite site of reddit (Haha) that someone claims to have solved it using the OpenVPN config files to force the plex.tv to be forwarded directly to the router:  https://www.reddit.com/r/PleX/comments/62h6ae/want_to_use_plex_behind_a_vpn_look_here/